# Django: How do you get user id on model.py page and set dynamically a default value

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models(Model Projects and Model Variables) in two apps (Projects app and Variables app). The models are not related in any ways.  I want to set the default value in Projects with value in Variables

```
Model Projects:
class Projects(models.Model):
    completion_time = models.FloatField(default='0')

Model Variables:
class Variables(models.Model):
    user_var_id = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    internal_completion_time = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

I want users to set a value in the variables and when they create a new project they would have that value from the variables be set as a default value for a new project by default. eg how could i do something like this

```
variable = Variables.Objects.Get(user_var_id=current_user_id-that i dont know how to get)

class Projects(models.Model):
    completion_time = models.FloatField(default=variable.internal_completion_time )
```

I thought it could be done by adding dynamically the default value, querying the variables filtering for the user and adding the value to the model but i dont know how to get the current user id on the model.py page. How can i do this maybe with another method.

Comment: You don't. You can not do that since models are request unaware. Furthermore management commands do not even have a user at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
#to get request in models.py
from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware
current_request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
```

pip install django-crequest

Step 1.Add crequest to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py

Step 2.Add crequest.middleware.CrequestMiddleware to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES after the authentication and session middleware.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crequest' - how would i use this in models

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rbtsolis/1db34b7d5a2ce9594f226cae414f9f12

Comment: https://medium.com/@ruhshan_ahmed/django-hack-how-to-access-request-object-from-models-6821d6107da

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save through Admin panel, try this:

```
class VariablesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user_var_id = request.user.id
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

If you want to save through api or view-set, try this:

```
variable = Variables()
variable.user_var_id = request.user.id
variable.save()
```

Comment: thanks for answer but not sure how to do that , if i use request on models page i get error

Comment: request object is used in admin class which is used in admin.py or api-view or function created in views.py like::

@api_view(["POST"])
def test_api(request):
     variable = Variables()
     variable.user_var_id = request.user.id
     variable.save()

Answer (score 0):

Inside your views, request.user.id will always return the id of the current user. You can simply use that in your queries to get the models you want.
You are also wrongly capitalizing both 'object' and 'get' in your code, which is incorrect.

So your query should look like this:

```
variable = Variables.objects.get(user_var_id=request.user.id)
```

EDIT: You seem to want access to a 'current user' inside your models file, rather than (logically) inside your views file; request.user.id is only available in views, since every view receives a request.

Comment: request cant be be used on model.py or i dont know how to use it on model.py  The capitalizing is a type i will correct , thank you

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is that when a user creates a project it will get the value from their variables.

What you can do is create a signal so when a project is created it will get the user and the related field and add that into the project and then save.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/

Comment: the models are not related , can you still do it

Comment: yes just import the models that you need and you can reference them from anywhere

Comment: @Gunnit https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Answer (score 0):

From @Surya Pratap Rana,
you can add the below in models.py

```
#to get request in models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware
from rest_framework.request     import Request
current_request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request(User)
```

and in your class that you need add user login as default

```
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=current_request)
```

I used this method in my program.